# AES password security using CryptoJS on client and Java's Cipher on server

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, javax.crypto

I am trying to encrypt the password sent by the client side using Javascript's [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js) 
and decrypt it on the server side using Java's [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class.

On Client Side :

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1/build/components/pad-nopadding.js"></script>
    <script>
        var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("A Sample Message", "SecretPassphrase", { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, iv: iv });
        console.log("iv: " + encrypted.iv.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
        console.log("ct: " + encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output i am getting on *Firebug* is

```
iv: a43e384b24e275c29a8a68bc031fd79e
ct: c86b6ca4ef30fadfea28821e04aa8dad
```

On server side :

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*;

public class AES {

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = "SecretPassphrase".getBytes();
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);

        byte[] iv = (byte[]) new Hex().decode("a43e384b24e275c29a8a68bc031fd79e");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);

        byte[] decordedValue = (byte[]) new Hex().decode(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);

        String decryptedValue = Hex.encodeHexString(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String result = AES.decrypt("c86b6ca4ef30fadfea28821e04aa8dad");
        System.out.println(hexToString(result));
    }
}
```

I need some help about what i am doing wrong and why am i getting random `iv` on my client side when i am restricting it to use passed iv.

Comment: _Do not encrypt passwords_.  You need to **hash** passwords, using bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: Also, client-side crypto won't add any security in most cases.  In particular, there is no escape from the need for SSL.

Comment: actually i need plaintext of password to match from my database.

Comment: No.  **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: I am getting the database from some other source.

Comment: You are passing a passphrase instead of a key at the client side. So it will do OpenSSL key derivation, probably generating an IV in there as well. Performing `SecretPassphrase".getBytes()` is something that you should never do either. Use hexadecimals if you want your key to be text, and convert it into binary using hexadecimal decoding.

Comment: @owlstead: then please suggest a way to use key on both sides.

Comment: I just did. Just handle it the same way you do the IV.

Comment: Some information on JavaScript cryptography: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: @owlstead: ur solution solved my problem, but now there is some other problem, when the encrypted text is not a multiple of 16, java gives error. Any idea what to do about that.

Comment: @ntoskrnl: i have read this page, but the requirements are something else.

Comment: Posting my solution as an answer. On your other question, any ciphertext created using ECB or CBC mode encryption should be a multiple of the blocksize in size. So if you have a ciphertext that does not comply to this then the ciphertext is faulty. This could be e.g. because you transferred the ciphertext as a string, instead of base 64 encoding it. If you still get the wrong ciphertext then you have an error condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a passphrase instead of a key at the client side. So it will do OpenSSL key derivation, probably generating an IV in there as well.

Performing `SecretPassphrase".getBytes()` is something that you should never do either. Use hexadecimals if you want your key to be text, and convert it into binary using hexadecimal decoding.